# generalization of these identities

Tags: nt.number-theory

In EM Wright's original paper, AN EASIER WARING'S PROBLEM (1934), he presents two nontrivial identities. The first is $(x+4)^4-2(x+3)^4+2(x+1)^4-x^4=48x+96$ and the second is $(x+3)^5-2(x+2)^5+x^5+(x-1)^5-2(x-3)^5+(x-4)^5=720x-360$. He doesn't say anything more, but assumes that others exist for higher powers. Do they exist? What do they look like and how can they be characterized?

Comment: The polynomials $(x+c_i)^n$ for distinct $c_0,\ldots,c_n$ are linearly independent (the matrix of coefficients is essentially Vandermonde matrix). Thus any $ax+b$ is their linear combination, and then we play with minimizing the sum of coefficients etc

Comment: I really hate to say it but I've no clue what you mean. Might you provide an example or a little more elaboration, please? What does it look like for exponent 6 or 7?

Comment: I mean that for any integer $a, b$ and any distinct integers $c_0,\ldots,c_n$ there exist unique rational numbers $p_0,\ldots,p_n$ such that $ax+b=\sum_{i=0}^n p_i(x+c_i)^n$. This is a linear system of equations with respect to $p_0,\ldots,p_n$ with a non-singular  matrix. Is this clear?